# Can 'get' be used in place of 'understand' when talking about classes?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, verbs, synonyms

Is it possible to use **get** as below to mean *'Do you understand this math lesson?'* :

> Do you get this math lesson?

If not how about :

> Are you getting this math lesson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either would be understood, at least in US usage. They can even be stated with "the math lesson" left off, "Do you get this?"/"Are you getting this?"

Comment: Thank you for your reply. On Duolingo.com I was downrated twice for suggesting this translation to *Vous comprenez cette leçon de mathématiques?*. https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/32070076

Comment: "get" is rather casual, which doesn't match the polite, formal style of the "vous comprendez" and  "mathématiques"

Comment: @JamesK Thank you for the point. If this is the reason they should make it clear somehow. Because it is quite often that Duolingo accepts alternative translations as long as the meaning is preserved.